# Prove that each element in a finite field with characteristic $p$ is a $p$-th power for exactly one element in that field.

Tags: field-theory

I want to prove that for each element $x$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$ there exists a unique element $y \in \mathbb{F}_q$ such that $x ^p = y$, with $p$ the characteristic of the given field.

$\forall x \in \mathbb{F}_q: x^q = x$, with $q = p^h, p$ prime, $h \ge 1$.
So we find $x^p = x^{1/h}$. Since the function $f:x\mapsto x^{1/h}$ is strictly monotonous, we can conclude that the property holds for $y = x^{1/h}$.

Is this a correct proof?

Comment: Your question's statement doesn't match the problem you state. For starters, "*power of*" means in english something different than what you want to say. Example: Some "powers of 3" are $3,3^2,3^3,\dots ,3^n$. On top of that, your notation is inconsistent and you use $q$ for the characteristic and $p$ for an arbitrary prime. I think you should edit your question.

Comment: $q$ is the order of $\mathbb{F}$, which is a power of $p$, the characteristic (a prime indeed).

Comment: What do you mean by a 'strictly monotonous' function on a finite field?

Comment: I think I just expressed myself incorrectly. What I intended to say was that the element $x^{1/h}$ will be unique.

Comment: If you raise to the $h$ power both sides of $x^p=x^{1/h}$ you get $x^{ph}=x$, which is different from $x^q=x$

Comment: You seem to be referring to the existence of the [Frobenius Automorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism). You can easily prove the problem statement by showing that $h(a)=a^p$ is an automorphism on $\mathbb F_q$ (or, put another way, an isomorphism from $\mathbb F_q$ to $\mathbb F_q$). The only slightly tricky thing here is to show that $h(a+b)=h(a)+h(b)$ is always satisfied (a proof can be found in the above linked wikipedia article). Regarding the proof you've presented, it doesn't look like you've shown that each element has an $h$th root.